# Build android project using maven with internal libraries

Tags: android, maven, maven-plugin, android-maven-plugin

I have an android library that uses native android libraries and and internal libraries. If I execute from eclipse like an android application all works but if I try to compile using maven (It is a maven project using eclipse and maven-android-plugin) it fails:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project devices: Compilation failure: Compilation
>   failure: [ERROR] /C:/android/device/epayment/gateway/PAX.java:[34,23]
>   C:\android\device\epayment\gateway\PAX.java:34: package
>   com.pax.poslink does not exist

My pom.xml contains:

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<finalName>../bin/${project.artifactId}</finalName>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
            <sdk>
                <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
                <platform>15</platform>
            </sdk>
        </configuration>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

It seems that the tag *nativeLibrariesDirectory* doesn't works for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a dependency to your library and host it in a Maven repo (and not a lib folder).